# Change FileField in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to update the pre-created model field which is `FileField`; this file is stored in the server, not in `request.FILES`.

My Model config is:

```py
class File(models.Model):
    fileID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    apkToolFile = models.FileField(null=True,upload_to='{}'.format(join(getattr(settings,'FILES_BASE'),getattr(settings,'APKTOOL_DIR_BASE'))))
    apkFile = models.FileField(null=True,upload_to='{}'.format(join(getattr(settings,'FILES_BASE'),getattr(settings,'APK_DIR_BASE'))))
    appPackage = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=30)
    appName = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=30)
    appIcon = models.FileField(upload_to='{}'.format(join(getattr(settings,'FILES_BASE'),getattr(settings,'APP_ICON_DIR'))),null=True)
    appVersion = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    hashFile = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=64)
    jadxFile = models.FileField(null=True,upload_to='{}'.format(join(getattr(settings,'FILES_BASE'),getattr(settings,'JADX_DIR_BASE'))))
    def __str__(self):
        return "FileName: {apkFile} - HashFile: {hashFile}".format(
            apkFile = self.apkFile, hashFile=self.hashFile
        )
```

And my Model serilazer is:

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from .models import File

    class FileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = File
            fields = [
                'fileID',
                'apkToolFile',
                'apkFile',
                'appPackage',
                'appName',
                'appIcon',
                'appVersion',
                'hashFile',
                'jadxFile'
            ]
```

I want to update `appIcon` with the file which is stored in the server storage. How can I do this?
Tank you

Comment: What do you mean It's stored in the server storage, the same server of django or an external server like amazon s3 ?

Comment: Is the icon a user generated content or you have a list of icons that you want to link to your database table

Comment: @ahmedosama I mean that file is not retrieved from the user, It opened from the file.

Comment: Have a look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/